# SSL Probleme with UTL_HTTP request

Tags: oracle, http, plsql, request

I am on oracle database 12.1

I would like to make an SSL request. But I have this error that appears.
I made an ACL file like this:

```
BEGIN
DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.CREATE_ACL(acl         => 'acl.xml',
                                  description => 'acces ACL',
                                  principal   => 'PUBLIC',
                                  is_grant    => true,
                                  privilege   => 'connect');

DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.ADD_PRIVILEGE(acl       => 'acl.xml',
                                    principal => 'PUBLIC',
                                    is_grant  => true,
                                     privilege => 'resolve');
DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.ADD_PRIVILEGE(
                                    acl         => 'acl.xml',
                                    principal   => 'PUBLIC',
                                    is_grant    =>  TRUE,
                                    privilege   => 'use-client- 
certificates');
DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.ASSIGN_ACL(acl  => 'acl.xml',
                                  host => 'www.example.com',
                                  lower_port => 443);

DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.ASSIGN_ACL(acl  => 'acl.xml',
                                  host => 'www.example-test.com',
                                  lower_port => 443);

DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.ASSIGN_WALLET_ACL (
   acl          => 'acl.xml',
   wallet_path  => 'file:F:\pathname'
   );



END;
```

I execute my next request:

```
  select utl_http.request('https://www.example.com',null,
  'file:F:\Certificat','password') from dual;
```

But I have this error :

```
ORA-29273: échec de demande HTTP
ORA-06512: à "SYS.UTL_HTTP", ligne 1720
ORA-28860: Erreur SSL irrémédiable
ORA-06512: à ligne 1
29273. 00000 -  "HTTP request failed"
*Cause:    The UTL_HTTP package failed to execute the HTTP request.
*Action:   Use get_detailed_sqlerrm to check the detailed error message.
       Fix the error and retry the HTTP request.
```

Is this someone would have an idea

thank you in advance

Comment: When you get this error, run this command next to get the actual HTTP error message. `select utl_http.get_detailed_sqlerrm from dual;`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have this response : GET_DETAILED_SQLERRM   :
ORA-28860: Erreur SSL irrémédiable